# Проблема с таблицами и css

Tags: html, css

Делаю таблицу -> https://jsfiddle.net/wfajwecc/3/

```
    <title></title>

<body>
    <table>
        <caption>Оставьте информацию о себе и мы вам обязательно перезвоним!</caption>
        <tr><td id="w33">Фамилия<td style=""><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname">
        <tr><td>Имя<td><input type"text" name="name" id="name">
        <tr><td>Отчество<td><input type="text" name="otchestvo" id="otchestvo">
        <tr><td>Добавьте фотографию<td><input id="photo" type="file">
        <tr><td>Адрес электронной почты<td><input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        <tr><td>Пароль:<td><input type="password" name="password1" id="password1">
        <tr><td>Повторите пароль:<td><input type="password" name="password2" id="password2">
        <tr><td>Адрес сайта<td><input placeholder="http://" type="password" name="password2" id="password2">
        <tr><td>Вы<td><input type="radio" name="sex" id="waoman">Женщина<input type="radio" name="sex" id="man">Мужчина
        <tr><td>Какие блюда вы предпочитаете?<td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="barbeku" id="barbeku">Шашлык<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="makaroni" id="makaroni">макароны
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="lapsha" id="lapsha">Куриная лапша
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name"borsh" id="borsh">Борщ
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name"pancakes" id="pancakes">Блины
            <tr><td style="cellpaddding:5px">Расскажите немного о себе<td><textarea cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
            <tr><td style="border: none;"><input type="submit" value="отправить"></input>
            <input type="reset" value="Очистить форму"></input>
    </table>
</body>
```

```
table{
width: 50%;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0 auto;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
caption {
font: bold italic 10pt Arial;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
margin-top: 5px;
}

#w33{
width: 33%;
}
```

Есть 3 вопроса, которые я пока не смог решить:

1. как сделать отступы внутри таблицы, кроме cellpadding, именно стилями почему-то не получается.
2. как сделать, чтобы ширина первой и второй колонки была по максимальной ширине контента, в моем случае во второй колонке максимальная ширина у radio Женский Мужской
3. Как сделать, чтобы в последней строке обе кнопки были по центру с небольшим отступом друг от друга, пробовал

   ```
   margin: 0 auto;
   ```

   не получается

Answer (score 3):

Решил долго не править твой код, НО у него много замечаний!

**Вот пример подкорректированный**: https://jsfiddle.net/csk5fsfk/

Ты не создаешь валидный DOM, ты не закрываешь теги `td`, не ставишь `=` в некоторых местах в `input` полях например.

1. Для объединения ячеек есть атрибут `colspan="<количество ячеек>"`
2. Отступы внутри задаются опцией `свойством padding` в стилях css (Пометил `<==` стрелкой в стилях)
3. Последний блок с кнопками отправить не был растянут по ширине всей таблицы, поэтому они не выравнивались, так же добавил свойство `text-align: center`, выравнивание по центру ячейки.

Все есть в примере + твоя задача сделать код валидным (полностью закрой теги, которые остались открыты)

Comment: Понял, спасибо, а по поводу вопроса с шириной второй колонки по максимальной ширине содержимого: как это сделать?